# How to launch Video Player when press on video link in WebView

Tags: android, webview, media-player

I am now doing Kid ABC song that I registered the YouTube link(example: lUJpRSLQ2kg) into my Database and I use PHP to retried the video as the "videolist.php" and I put it in WebView Activity then I need to play Video Player Activity when user perform hyperlink click on youtube video id in Android WebView Activity.

video_list.php in WebView (listing only youtube link id only example: 7mOQb3E8ob0. Not full link like this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7mOQb3E8ob0)

```
<a href=\"kidabcsong://MediaPlayer_Activity/vid=<?=$sqlVideoResultList['fileurl']?>\">
<img src=\"<?=$sqlVideoResultList['imageurl']?>\">
</a>
```

My question is: how to make Video Player activity get the video ID from WebView and play?

Thank you so much for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use youtube player, First, register and get Id, then

```
Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(args);
startActivity(intent);
```